# Has anyone found a way to change ALT+Tab behaviour?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

I don't like the behaviour of the Alt + Tab shortcut when changing between windows. How can I change to something like macOS where you see a line of icons rather than changing windows?
[image]

I found a project in github but im not sure if it is safe to use
https://github.com/jibbo/gala-elementary-alt-tab-switcher

Answer (score 0):

The repo you mentioned is updated quite recently, so it is worth to try.
Seems you need dconf-editor to enable this.

See [here](https://github.com/p0pye/gala-elementary-alt-tab-switcher/issues/2#issuecomment-453174785) for more details.